# Issues in Controlling a .Net windows service

Tags: c#, windows, task-parallel-library

I've a C# windows service running on a Windows 2012 R2 Standard edition.
We stop and start this service using Service Control Manager(SCM) on a daily basis and this has been running fine in the past.

But recently, we are seeing a behaviour in which:

1.We needed to increase the timeout for start and stop functionality of the service

2.Also, when we tried to stop the service, we see that the Stop button(and Start button as well) are greyed out for this service in the SCM.So this forced us to go to the task manager, kill the service and start it again.

Just wondering whats the reason for this behaviour.

Apparently, this seems to have started recently after adding following code in the constructor of Service :

```
 foreach (Product p in Products)
            {
                Parallel.Invoke(() => {//Call a third part web service1}
        Parallel.Invoke(() => {//Call a third part web service2}
    }
```

(The products list is 200 here)

So needed to know if this particular code change is really the reason for this behavior??Please advise.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

your `Parallel.Invoke` call seems pointless, you only call one action from the invoke, that is causing your code to be equivalent to

```
 foreach (Product p in Products)
 {
        {//Call a third part web service1}
        {//Call a third part web service2}
 }
```

You can see why that could take a while to run.

However, even if you fixed that issue, just because it is parallel does not mean it is fast. Don't do heavy work in the constructor, spawn a new thread in `OnStart` and do this work there.

Comment: Ok.Thanks.And how do we explain the reason for Stop button showing as greyed out please?

Comment: Once a service is in a "faulted" state for taking too long the whole system breaks down, it stops trying to talk to the service.